# Java generic subtype of Class cannot be passed/returned without extensive casting

Tags: java, generics

I have a `JsonService` that has a method like this...

```
<T> T readObject(String json, Class<T> clz);
```

And this works fine when I invoke it like this:

```
SomeBeanImpl bean = jsonService.readObject(json, SomeBeanImpl.class);
```

But I would like to enforce passing only classes that implement the marker interface `JsonBean` (I want to be able to easily identify what is being treated as JSON and run tests on those classes, among other reasons). So I changed the method signature to:

```
<T> JsonBean<T> readObject(String json, Class<? extends JsonBean<T>> clz);
```

Now I have lots of compilation errors - can't cast this, can't match that... but it will work if I call it like this:

```
SomeBeanImpl bean = (SomeBeanImpl) jsonService.readObject(s, 
    (Class<? extends JsonBean<SomeBeanImpl>>) SomeBeanImpl.class);
```

That's kind of a big mess and would have to be repeated everywhere that the service is used. Is there some way around it, or is this use case just too complex for generics?

Comment: If you have many problems with that code I think you can check for implementing specific interface by: if(JsonBean.class.isAssignableFrom(clz)); instea

Comment: can you code it to the interface `JsonBean bean = jsonService.readObject(json, SomeBeanImpl.class);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description doesn't match your code. If you want to be able to pass only classes implementing a marker interface you need something like this,

```
<T extends JsonBean> T readObject(String json, Class<T> clz);
```

And you don't even need JsonBean to accept a generic parameter.

Now if `SomeBeanImpl` implements `JsonBean` you will be able to pass it, otherwise not.

Comment: I didn't even think of trying to modify that... I will try it and see

Answer (score -1):

You should just declare `JsonBean` class, don't declare it as `JsonBean<T>`.